# Using a lambda function to search for specific text then modify that text in the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

junior dev here.

I'm trying to create an "onshore" and "offshore" tag for a report. I'm trying to use a lambda function to search for specific text in my data frame then override the cell in the data frame if conditions are met.

Dataset:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Current Output:

[image]

Current Code:

```
df['Office_Address'] = df.apply(lambda x: "onshore" if ((x['Employment_Type'] == 'Consultant') and (x['Office_Address'] == str.contains('United States of America', regex = True))) else x['Office_Address'] == "offshore", axis = 1)
```

I believe my issue is within the use of `str.contains()` which returns a boolean value, hence the current output. I'm not certain how to get the if statement to only trigger when it sees the partial text of `"United States of America"`. My dataset varies in the placement of the United States of America tag but I know it's always spelled that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing a `True` or `False` is because the final statements e.g.:

```py
else x['Office_Address'] == "offshore"
```

is a boolean statement of whether that row value equals 'offshore' which evaluates to a boolean value. This can be updated to just return

```py
"offshore"
```

So the full example would be:

```py
df['Office_Address'] = df.apply(lambda x: "onshore" if ((x['Employment_Type'] == 'Consultant') and ('United States of America' in x['Office_Address'])) else "offshore", axis = 1)
```

To improve your code even further you can take advantage of pandas' ability to operate on large amounts of data using column level operations. They are usually more efficient than something like `pd.apply`. (see https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/)

With that in mind, this example can do a direct column modification:

```py
df.loc[(df['Employment_Type'] == 'Consultant') & (df['Office_Address'].str.contains('United States of America', regex = True)], 'Office_Address'] = "onshore" 
df.loc[!(df['Office_Address'] == 'onshore')], 'Office_Address'] = "offshore"
```

The statement above uses `.loc[rows, columns]`. This can be thought of as set the values 'at the **loc**ation of' these rows and these columns. In this case the rows to update are those which have `Employment_Type` equal to 'Consultant' and `Office_Address` containing the 'United States of America', and sets the `Office_Address` value for these rows to 'onshore'. Once it's done that, it sets the values for the remaining rows to 'offshore' by elimination.

Comment: Hi grbeazley, I've been troubleshooting this. At first, I thought it was working since the else statement was putting in the "offshore" however the search for USA isn't working. 

I'm getting an attribute error 'str' object has no attribute 'str'. when I change == Consultant to !=Employee to see if it will run the if statement.

I also tried your direct column modification and that didn't work either.

Comment: Hi davida28, I've updated the code for the `str.contains` to use the `in` statement. What happens when you run the direct column modification, do you see an error or just not get the desired result?

Comment: I figured out what happened. There's a statement that changed the naming convention above this line so the ```if``` statement never executes. What you wrote above works perfectly.